# How to scroll a sync'd up MotionLayout+AppBarLayout programmatically?

Tags: android, android-motionlayout

Consider the following [Coordinator+AppBar](https://github.com/android/views-widgets-samples/blob/main/ConstraintLayoutExamples/motionlayout/src/main/res/layout/motion_11_coordinatorlayout.xml)+[MotionLayout](https://github.com/android/views-widgets-samples/blob/main/ConstraintLayoutExamples/motionlayout/src/main/res/layout/motion_11_coordinatorlayout_header.xml) and its [MotionScene](https://github.com/android/views-widgets-samples/blob/main/ConstraintLayoutExamples/motionlayout/src/main/res/xml/scene_11_header.xml) from Google's demo. This creates a MotionLayout that sync's its Transition progress when the user is scrolling.

Video Preview: https://i.imgur.com/1MnPB8R.mp4

However, I would like to do this in programmatically in Kotlin. Here are my failed attempts.

```
val motion = findViewById<MotionLayout>(R.id.constraintToolbar)
motion.transitionToState(R.id.end)
```

The above would cause the MotionLayout to animate, but would immediately blink back to the `start` state once finished. The AppBarLayout also does not change height.

```
val appbar = findViewById<AppBarLayout>(R.id.app_bar)
val scrollable = findViewById<NestedScrollView>(R.id.scrollable)
val s = if(motion.progress==0F) appbar.totalScrollRange else 0
scrollable.smoothScrollTo(0, s)
```

The above scrolls the NestedScrollView, but the AppBarLayout and MotionLayout does not receive the scroll events.

```
val s = if(motion.progress==0F)-appbar.totalScrollRange else 0
val appbar = findViewById<AppBarLayout>(R.id.app_bar)
appbar.scrollTo(0,s)
appbar.offsetTopAndBottom(s)
```

The above shifts the AppBarLayout, breaking the layout completely.

How do you trigger this scroll programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's only 2 states, you should try `setExpanded()`

```
val e = motion.progress != 0F
appbar.setExpanded(e, true)
```